# Find Left ,top and right position of div positioned block relative to parent div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image: sektch]

I want position red box div above the DIV B which is position block and centered.
DIVA is position relative.
I have reference

```
DIV B useRef -> containerRef

const OutlineElement = (props) => {
    var contanierDom = containerRef.current[props.index].getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(contanierDom);
    let bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    let de = document.documentElement;
  const styles2 = {
    width:contanierDom.width,    // computed based on child and parent's height
    height:contanierDom.height,
    left:contanierDom.left,
    top:contanierDom.top,
  };
  const styles1 = {
    right:contanierDom.right,
    top:contanierDom.top,
  };
  return (
    <>
    <div class="builder-tool builder-outline-content-hover" style={styles1} ref={saveContentRef(props.index)} >block</div>
    <div class="builder-tool builder-hover-outline"  style={styles2} ref={saveOutlineRef(props.index)}></div>
    </>
  );
```

I need to calculate  the right most position of DIV B and place the redbox in absloute.

```
<div class="content">
        <div className="wrapper_builder">
              <div class="page_layout">
              <div builder-element="BlockElement" onDragStop={(e) => {handleContainerDragStop(e,index)}} onDragOver={(e) => {handleContanierDragOver(e,index)}} onDragEnter={(e) => {handleContainerDragEnter(e)}} builder-container builder-wrapper  ref={saveContainerRef(index)}  className={hovered ? '"container container_blank builder-class-element-highlighted' : '"container container_blank'} onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
      onMouseLeave={toggleHover}>
                
              </div>
              {hovered && <OutlineElement index={index}/>}
              {dragOver && <DragHighliter index={index}/>}
              
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

OutlineElement  will be shown on hovering DIV B.

I trying to calculate the position of left,right and top. But could not.

```
const styles2 = {
    width:contanierDom.width,    // computed based on child and parent's height
    height:contanierDom.height,
    left:contanierDom.left,
    top:contanierDom.top,
  };
  const styles1 = {
    right:contanierDom.right,
    top:contanierDom.top,
  };
```

How do  I get the left right and top position of DIV B?

```
DIVB =BlockElement
DIVA=Content
REDBOX =  builder-outline-content-hover
```

Comment: *"which is position block "* - No such thing.

Comment: Put the red block *inside* DIVB and the position it **absolutely** in relation to DIVB

Comment: No I will n number of DIVB blocks

Comment: I need calculate the position. Need to do some maths here to get left,right and top

Comment: No you really don't.